# How are delegate methods used

Tags: iphone, delegates

I am trying to use a delegate method in my simple iPhone application but I got an error.
If there are any examples code; pls send me a link or code.

Comment: Hold on why I use my psychic powers to see your error. Or just post it along with some code as I just had a margarita which might block my psychic powers

Comment: Which delegate method?  Post your code, we'll help you fix it.  There are many, many different delegate methods.

Comment: You forgot to capitalize the second word in the method name. That should fix it, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

When using delegates there are a few things to take care of.

For example, say you have a class `MyController` and you want it to be a `UITextField`'s delegate. Put the delegate protocol name in the class's interface:

```
@interface MyController : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then, implement the delegate methods in the `UITextFieldDelegate` docs (the docs say "All of the methods of this protocol are optional." so you can choose which you want):

```
@implementation MyController
...

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    // do something
}

...
@end
```

Then finally, set yourself as the delegate:

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```